# Moser iteration epsilon-regularity for non-linear system in general dimension

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde

I am attempting to prove the following result in general dimension $n$. Given $(M^n,g)$ a Riemannian manifold with $\mathrm{Ric}_g \geq -(n-1)$ and $\mathrm{Vol}_g(B_1(x)) \geq v > 0$ for all $x \in M^n$. There then exists $\epsilon = \epsilon(v)>0$, and $C = C(v)>0$ such that if $u$ obeys $\Delta_g u \geq -u^2$ on $B_2(p)$, and $\int_{B_2(p)} u^2 d\mathrm{vol}_g < \epsilon$, then we can conclude $\|u\|_{L^\infty(B_1(p))} \leq C \|u\|_{L^2(B_2(p))}$.

In the case $n=4$ it can be proven with Moser iteration, using the Holder inequality and Sobolev inequalities to bound the non-linear term. However, I can not seem to get this to work for the general case as the dual exponent $p^\ast = \frac{np}{n-p}$ does not seem to work.

Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: I'm also happy to elaborate more if that might help :)

Comment: I need to double check this but my recollection is that you need the $L^{n/2}$ norm to be sufficiently small and an $L^p$ bound for some $p > 1$. If it’s possible to do better than this, I doubt the proof is easy.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best possible result, and I'm sure there's a better reference than this, but you can look at Appendix B of my paper. http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=ASENS_1992_4_25_2_179_0

Comment: Hello, yes this works! It should be for the $L^{n/2}$ norm. Thank you!